# JavaScript function not calling ActionResult

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a DropDownList on my Razor page

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Clubs, new SelectList(ViewBag.Clubs as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Id", "Name"),
                          "-- Select a club --",
                          new { id = "ddlClubs" })
```

That populates another DropDownList with a Json call from a javascript function:

```
$(function () {
  $("#ddlClubs").change(function () {
  var clubid = $(this).val();
  $.getJSON("../Administration/LoadCompsByClubId", { clubid: clubid },
    function (compsData) {
      var select = $("#ddlComps");
      select.empty();
      select.append($('<option/>', {
      value: 0,
      text: "-- select a competition --"
  }));
  $.each(compsData, function (index, itemData) {
    select.append($('<option/>', {
      value: itemData.Value,
      text: itemData.Text
    }));
  });
});
```

This DropDownList is correctly populated.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Id", new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),
                    "Id", "Name"),  "-- select a competition --",
                    new{
                        id = "ddlComps",
                        data_url = Url.Action("GetTeams", "Administration")
                    })
```

Now when I call the change function to load the `ActionResult` into the div, the associated `GetTeams` Action is not being called.

```
 $(function () {
    $('#ddlComps').change(function () {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('#result').load(url, { id: value });

    });
});
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Bet it is simple as usual...

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you write how this action that returns other drop down values looks like. To me it sounds like you are not returning JsonResult (extends ActionResult), but I cannot tell more than I see.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the LoadCompsByClubId method on the AdministrationController it seems that the following URL would require some funny routing configuration to be routed to the correct controller.

$.getJSON("../Administration/LoadCompsByClubId", { clubid: clubid }

Are you sure that the above should not be just this would be the default for an mvc controller action.

$.getJSON("/Administration/LoadCompsByClubId", { clubid: clubid }

If you look at the HTTP traffic in fiddler or your browser debugger do you see the request and response to and from the server?